# Javascript hide element onclick, does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, visibility

I created a little table in which you can click the datacells, what will trigger my Javascript to call a function. This function shows a little "formular" at the position of the clicked datacell. Now I added a button, that should hide this formular, but it does not work and I don't know why.

HTML:

```
<div id="movableDiv">
<form>
<p>Some text:</p>
<input type="text" name="someText">
<p>A number:</p>
<input type="number" name="aNumber">
<button type="button" ="HideButton">
Hide
</button>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#movableDiv{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("HideButton").onclick = hideDiv;
function hideDiv(){
document.getElementById("movableDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qc1dng63/2/

Comment: your script seems it's loaded before the html , so there an error "cannot set onclick of undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. Your code to attach event listeners should be in `window.onload`.
2. Your loop should be `td.length-1`. Instead of your code, you can use `[].forEach.call` to replace the below code:

`//all datacells safed in variable
var datacells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
//length of array
var cellsCount = datacells.length;
//iterate through array
for (var i = 0; i <= cellsCount; i += 1) {
    //if any of this datacells get clicked, it will call function "example" with id of clicked element as parameter
    datacells[i].onclick = example;
}`

Below is the updated code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
 [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("td"), function (el) {
  el.onclick = example;
 })

 //if clicked elsewhere, div has to become hidden again.

 //onlick hide, div box becomes hidden again
 document.getElementById("HideButton").onclick = hideDiv;
}

//functions
function example(idOfDatacells) {
 //this references the element, which called the function
 var rect = document.getElementById(this.id).getBoundingClientRect();

 document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = rect.top;
 document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = rect.left;

 var div = document.getElementById("movableDiv");
 div.style.visibility = "visible";
 div.style.top = rect.top + document.getElementById(this.id).clientHeight + "px";
 div.style.left = rect.left + "px";
}

//function for hiding formular
function hideDiv() {
 document.getElementById("movableDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
table {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
}

td {
 text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(2) {
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

tr {
 height: 50px;
}

#movableDiv {
 background-color: lightgrey;
 position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Header1</th>
  <th>Header2</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="tr1tc1">Data1</td>
  <td id="tr1tc2">Data2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="tr2tc1">Data3</td>
  <td id="tr2tc2">Data4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<div id="movableDiv">
 <form>
  <p>Some text:</p>
  <input type="text" name="someText">
  <p>A number:</p>
  <input type="number" name="aNumber">
  <button id="HideButton" type="button">
Hide
</button>
 </form>
</div>
<p id="top">
 Top:
</p>
<p id="left">
 Left:
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain `[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("td"), function (el) {
  el.onclick = example;` ?

Answer (score 0):

In this style you have added below css

```
#movableDiv{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

here visibility hidden is hide all given html

Answer (score 0):

Append onclick event when document is already loaded, in your fiddle I have found that you try to append before document loads itself, so it will not work.

better solution will be

your html here

```
<script>
    function load(){
document.getElementById("HideButton").onclick = hideDiv;
}

//another functions

</script>
```

of cource, hideDiv must be defined somewhere.

this will ensure that HideButton will be loaded and defined when you try to append event.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the fact that you can not assign onclick functions to hidden elements. Because of this your button never gets bound to the function hideDiv.

So I moved the lines:

```
//onlick hide, div box becomes hidden again
document.getElementById("HideButton").onclick = hideDiv;
```

inside the function example.

Here: https://jsfiddle.net/qc1dng63/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= cellsCount - 1; i++) {
    //if any of this datacells get clicked, it will call function "example" with id of clicked element as parameter
   datacells[i].onclick = example;
}
```

you need `cellCount - 1`

Comment: You are right, but why is this not a problem in Javascript? I mean it works anyway

Comment: @Denis.Sabolotni yes, the problem is that your for loop is going from 0 to 4,  since you used `<=` and loop is trying to bind "4" and that would be 5th item. since index goes from 0. Hope you understand